# How protect Amazon S3 via Basic Authentification

Tags: amazon-s3, basic-authentication

I am new to S3 and am wonding how I could protect access to S3 or cloud front via Basic Authentification while installing a private certificate into Chrome, that allows access. Is there anything like this?

Comment: Are you using the term "basic authentication" in the [proper technical sense](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), or do you mean something else? What is your desired end result, from a user experience perspective?

Comment: Yes I mean pw protect it. I want to host files that are not visible to the public until official go live of the application using s3

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use Basic Authentication with Amazon S3 nor Amazon CloudFront.

Amazon S3 access can be controlled via one or more of:

- [Access Control List on the object level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)
- [Amazon S3 Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)
- [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html)

Amazon CloudFront has its own method of controlling access via [signed URLs and signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).